# Can I import npm packages dynamically from CDNs in Webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-4

I need to require a different version of [Zoid](https://github.com/krakenjs/zoid) npm package dynamically in my JS bundle, depending on a variable. So for example:

```js
if (isLatestVersion) {
  zoid = await import('https://unpkg.com/zoid@9.0.80/index.js')
} else {
  zoid = await import('https://unpkg.com/zoid@9.0.31/index.js')
}
```

However when I try the above I get this error:

```
script.js:2 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Cannot find module 'https://unpkg.com/zoid@9.0.80/index.js'
    at webpackMissingModule (script.js:2)
```

Presumably this is because I don't have `zoid` defined in my package.json.

So basically my question is, is there's a way to import libraries from a CDN such as unpkg.com or skypack.dev, using Webpack's dynamic imports (aka code splitting)?

Comment: This should work in general. Maybe you can post your package.json and webpack.config.js? Is there a reason, why you use webpack 4 and not 5?

Answer (score 0):

The way I ended up solving this was by adding two versions of the same package in my package.json. So I ran these commands:

```
yarn add zoid9080@npm:zoid@9.0.80
yarn add zoid9031@npm:zoid@9.0.31
yarn remove zoid
```

Then I imported these two packages statically, since I didn't actually need dynamic importing, and the code ended up being simpler as well:

```
import zoid from 'zoid9080';
```